# Dialog using DialogFragment not showing up properly

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am using DialogFragment to display a dialog.But the dialog was displayed with the title.When i used no title my dialog was not being displayed properly.

Dialog with title
[image]

Dialog without title

[image]

Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/share_background"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Share"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

DialogFragment Code

```
public class ShareDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.share_dialog, null, false);
       getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return view;
    }


}
```

Why this is happening????

Comment: Have you tried to put the `android:layout_width` properties of your `LinearLayout`s to `wrap_content`?

Comment: Which LinearLayout????

Comment: Both... it could be the problem

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27236008/925070

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Share"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem was the TextView's `width` value being `"wrap_content"`. The `android:gravity="center"` property was only to center your text as you wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Fix layout height and width of your parent linear layout to a fixed value.

Example:

```
 android:layout_width="200dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.share_dialog, container, false);
```