# FragmentDialog with custom layout and without title not maximized

Tags: android

I am creating a dialog for which I don't need a title area so I just disable it inside onCreateView like this:

```
getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

The problem with this approach is that after I do this, dialog is not displayed correctly. It doesn't show whole content of the inflated layout and it is really small. If I remove that line of code, dialog is displayed perfectly fine.

What could be causing this problem and how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27236008/925070

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `onCreate` method like below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth);
}
```